# Why does scipy minimize return such bad estimates?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to use scipy minimize to estimate a parameter from an ODE system, which is pretty straightforward, however the methods I used  aren't returning values anywhere near what the value should be. My parameter `beta`, should have a value estimated to be around 0.42. I am sure that this method is correct, so i can't understand why the estimates are so off

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

t = np.linspace(0, 77, 77+1)
d = {'Week': [t[7],t[14],t[21],t[28],t[35],t[42],t[49],t[56],t[63],t[70],t[77]], 
     'incidence': [206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,
                   7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def peak_infections(beta, df):
 
    # Weeks for which the ODE system will be solved
    #weeks = df.Week.to_numpy()

    # Total population, N.
    N = 100000
    # Initial number of infected and recovered individuals, I0 and R0.
    I0, R0 = 10, 0
    # Everyone else, S0, is susceptible to infection initially.
    S0 = N - I0 - R0
    J0 = I0
    # Contact rate, beta, and mean recovery rate, gamma, (in 1/days).
    #reproductive no. R zero is beta/gamma
    gamma = 1/6 #rate should be in weeks now
    # A grid of time points 
    times = np.arange(7,84,7)

    # The SIR model differential equations.
    def deriv(y, times, N, beta, gamma):
        S, I, R, J = y
        dS = ((-beta * S * I) / N)
        dI = ((beta * S * I) / N) - (gamma * I)
        dR = (gamma * I)
        dJ = ((beta * S * I) / N) #incidence
        return dS, dI, dR, dJ

    # Initial conditions are S0, I0, R0
    # Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
    solve = odeint(deriv, (S0, I0, R0, J0), times, args=(N, beta, gamma))
    S, I, R, J = solve.T

    return I/N

def residual(x, df):

    # Total population,  N.
    N = 100000
    incidence = df.incidence.to_numpy()/N
    return np.sum((peak_infections(x,df) - incidence) ** 2)

x0 = 0.5
res = minimize(residual, x0, args=(df), method="Nelder-Mead", options={'fatol':1e-04}).x
print(res)

best = leastsq(residual, x0,args=(df))
print(best) #tried this using leastsq too

results = minimize_scalar(residual,(0.4, 0.5),args=(df))
print(results)
results['fun']
```

As you can see I have used minimize, minimize_scalar and even leastsq. They all returns values such as 0.723. Where have I gone wrong? Is my objective function `return np.sum((peak_infections(x,df) - incidence) ** 2)` at least correct?

edit: i tried taking the `np.max(I/N)` in the `peak_infections(beta, df)` function however this does not return a correct estimate either

Edit2: code to test real data with beta estimates:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#three compartments, Susceptible S, infected I, recovered R
#dS/dt, dI/dt, dR/dt
#susceptible sees birth rate coming in, deaths leaving and force of infection leaving
#infected sees FOI coming in, deaths leaving and recovery rates
#recovered sees recovery rate coming in, deaths leaving
#beta is tranmission coefficient, FOI is beta * (I/N) where N is total pop
#initially consider a model not accounting for births and death

# Total population, N.
N = 100000
# Initial number of infected and recovered individuals, I0 and R0.
I0, R0 = 10, 0
# Everyone else, S0, is susceptible to infection initially.
S0 = N - I0 - R0
J0 = I0
# Contact rate, beta, and mean recovery rate, gamma, (in 1/days).
#reproductive no. R zero is beta/gamma
beta, gamma = 0.4205, 1/6
# A grid of time points (in days)
t = np.linspace(0, 77, 77+1)
t7 = np.arange(0, 84, 7)
t1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
t1 =  [element * 7 for element in t1]
t1 = np.array(t1)

# The SIR model differential equations.
def deriv(y, t7, N, beta, gamma):
    S, I, R, J = y
    dS = ((-beta * S * I) / N)
    dI = ((beta * S * I) / N) - (gamma * I)
    dR = (gamma * I)
    dJ = ((beta * S * I) / N)
    return dS, dI, dR, dJ

# Initial conditions are S0, I0, R0
# Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
solve = odeint(deriv, (S0, I0, R0, J0), t7, args=(N, beta, gamma))
S, I, R, J = solve.T


d = {'Week': [t[0], t[7],t[14],t[21],t[28],t[35],t[42],t[49],t[56],t[63],t[70],t[77]], 'incidence': [0,206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.plot(x='Week', y='incidence')


J_diff = J[0:] - J[:1]
J_diff = np.diff(J)
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='w')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor='#dddddd', axisbelow=True)
#ax.plot(t, J, 'red', alpha=1, lw=2, label='Cumulative incidence')
ax.plot(t7[1:], J_diff, 'blue', alpha=1, lw=2, label='Daily incidence')
ax.plot(t1[1:], df.incidence, 'r', alpha=1, lw=2, label='weekly data')
ax.set_xlabel('Time in days')
ax.set_ylabel('Number')
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', c='w', lw=2, ls='-')
legend = ax.legend()
legend.get_frame().set_alpha(0.5)

plt.show()
```

returns this fit for beta = 0.4205

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the model is OK, the problem is that you assume that `beta` should be close to `0.42` when it should not. A simple visual test, plotting the measurements and the modeled data, shows that `0.72` yields much better results than `0.43`. I added the following lines:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(d['Week'], df.incidence.to_numpy()/100000, label="Real data")
plt.plot(d['Week'], peak_infections(.72, df), label="Model with 0.72")
plt.plot(d['Week'], peak_infections(.42, df), label="Model with .42")
plt.legend()
```

which yielded the following figure:

[image: Comparision of beta values]

It is clear that `0.72` **is** a better estimate of `beta` than `0.42`, even without plotting the residuals.

As a side note, be careful because your code is easy to break.You define the same values in many places: `N` is defined inside `peak_infections` and `residual`. The days of the week are defined as `d['Week']` and as `times` inside `peak_infections`. It is easy to change the value of one of these variables in one place and forget to change it in another place. Moreover, I see no use of `pandas` here, since you do not take profit of its features on top of `numpy`.

Comment: that is really peculiar, because when I tested these estimates of beta in some seperate code I wrote (please see the edit), I achieved a much better fit with 0.4205 (see attached plot in edit)

Comment: Also, what do you mean regarding my use of pandas?

Comment: There are big differences in your edit: a) you included a time `0` with `0` cases. If you do that in the original code, you will get a beta of `0.53925781`. b) You are plotting against `np.diff(J)` instead of `I`: it is not only a different magnitude (`I` and `J`), but it also shifts the time position by one. Regarding the use of pandas, I mean that you do not access data in the dataframe by name (in the first edit): you could have used plain numpy arrays

Comment: Yes, for the beta value, my hope was to get an estimate that when I plot the outputs, it matches as close to np.diff(J) as possible. Have I done it wrong in that case? Also, in my original code, I did use pandas in `df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`